# Microsoft Graph access onenote as deamon service returns invalid scope

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access onenote pages from users within my organization as a deamon service, so the users won't sign in, it will be a background service running.

I've followed this tutorial more or less: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

I've setup the necessary API permissions and they've been granted by admin.
[image]

I then request a OAuth token which works fine. And then I send a request for the Onenote pages

```
import requests

payload = {
    'client_id': '<my_client_id_is_here>',
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'client_secret': '<my_client_secret_is_here>',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
},

 tenant_id = "<my_tenant_id_is_here>"

response = requests.post(
    url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token'.format(
        tenant_id
    ),
    data=payload 
)
token = json.loads(response.content)

test_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<my-sharepoint-site-id>/onenote/sections/<my-onenote-section-id>/pages?top=100'


response = requests.get(
    url=test_url,
    headers={
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']
    }
)
print(response.content)
```

When i print the response I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "40004",
        "message": "The OAuth token provided does not have the necessary scopes to complete the request. Please make sure you are including one or more of the following scopes: Notes.ReadWrite.All,Notes.Read.All",
            "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-08-18T06:17:51",
            "request-id": "1042af2a-ddc8-4c72-84b2-56f0079d6174"
        }
    }
}
```

I've have tried changing the `scope` to `'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/notes.readwrite.all',` but then the token request doesn't work. With the error message 'scope parameter is not valid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had accidentally choosen the legacy onenote API endpoint for my permissions instead of the Microsoft Graph OneNote endpoint that I was trying to use.